# how to maintain session for 2 different browsers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session, browser

I done project in ASP.net MVC3. In my project i create a session as follows in Home Controller

```
if (Session["ulclass"] == null)
     {
                    Session["ulclass"] = "list";
     }
```

I use this session to my Product List page.. as a class for div tag as follows..

```
<div id="listheading" class="listHead" @if (Session["ulclass"].ToString() == "grid")
                                       {
                                           <text>style = "display:none;";</text>
                                       }>
```

When i copy this Productlist URL from FireFox to Chrome...
session value not come.. it produce the error...

Can any one help this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cookieless sessions. That way the session id is sent in the URL instead of a cookie, so then you could just copy the URL anywhere and you are still in the same session.

Put this in web.config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

(The drawback is of course that anyone can copy the URL anywhere and still be in your session...)

More about cookieless session: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

Comment: inthis project i use one more session that dosen't create when copy url to another page

Comment: @Prakash: The session object is not created when you copy the URL to a new browser, it will use the already existing session object. That means that it only works for as long as the session object remains on the server. If you want a permanent URL that you can use later, you have to put enough information in the URL to create a new session object, and you need code in the page to create the session object if it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Convert.ToString(Session["ulclass"]) == "grid" to avoid error first, and then add  in we.config